# Get a value of specific cell from excel sheet using python

Tags: python

Suppose I have an excel sheet

| Name | Id | Message |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alex | 123 | Hello |
| Mike | 453 | Hey There |
| Andy | 865 | How are you? |
| Ricky | 987 | Hi |

I want to get an individual cell and use it as a variable in python
First I want to get Alex, use it, then get Mike and so on

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: What are you using to read the excel sheet?

Comment: please show some research effort or code you have already written

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/index.html) for that.

```
import pathlib
import pandas

excel_file_path = pathlib.Path('my.xlsx')

df = pandas.read_excel(excel_file_path)

print(df.Name)  # something like ['Alex', 'Mike', 'Andy', 'Ricky']
```

This example assumes that there is only one sheet in the Excel file. The data starts at the first cell (A1) and the first row includes the column names.

Another package you could use is [`openpyxl`](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).